# PHP, MySQL: Making a better search?

Tags: php, mysql, search

I've made a search box feature that allows me to type in a word and then it finds any matches of the word in my database.  However, it only finds EXACT matches.  I'm looking for suggestions on how to make the search better.

The code below is what i currently use for searching the databases for users that might be matches for the user searching.

```
    $search_keys = array('fname', 'lname', 'email' );

    foreach ( $search_keys as $key )
    {
        $result = mysql_query( "SELECT id FROM users WHERE " . $key . " LIKE " . "\"{$str}\"" ) or die(mysql_error());

        while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) )
        {

            // Get the User
            $tmp_user = new User();
            $tmp_user->getUserById( $row['id'] );

            // Add User to list of potential candidates
            array_push($users, $tmp_user);
        }
    }
```

Comment: keep in mind that using the `LIKE` method ignores the index, and makes searches crawl depending on your data subset

Comment: Not totally true. It will only ignore the index if the search term is fully surrounded, however if it only ends with a % - for example `Jam%`, it will use the index. Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see two points where you can improve your code fragment. But first of all take care that $str is properly formatted to be safely used in your SQL query. Otherwise you will run into a problem called [SQL Injection](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/guide-to-php-security.html). I assume that now for your code.

1. Use wildcards with [the LIKE SQL function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html).
2. Search across the three fields with one SQL query.

Please see the example code which contains both suggestions. First the SQL query is build. There is only need to run one query for all (three) fields instead of one query per field. That's useful if you extend your search later.

```
/* build SQL query */
$conditions = array();
$search_keys = array('fname', 'lname', 'email' );
foreach ( $search_keys as $key )
{
    $conditions[] = "{$key} LIKE \"%{$str}%\""; # Wildcard (%); [] works like array_push()
}
$query = sprintf('SELECT id FROM users WHERE (%s)', implode(' OR ', $conditions));

/* run SQL query */
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) )
{
    // Get the User
    $tmp_user = new User();
    $tmp_user->getUserById( $row['id'] );

    // Add User to list of potential candidates
    array_push($users, $tmp_user);
}
```

Comment: I think your line on 11 should be $result = mysql_query( $query );

Comment: This is an excellent start, I was able to modify for a much broader search. Thanks for the framework, this is a gem.

Answer (score 2):

Well there is always the simplest method of adding the wildcard operator, so if they enter 'Jam' it would be

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE fname LIKE '%Jam%'
etc...
```

EDIT: The point being it would return a match on JAMIE or JAMES or LogJam or (you get the idea), which means they don't need to remember the whole name, just some part of it.

Comment: however also the slowest possible approach, and with thousands or records you will see this crawl.

Comment: What's a better approach then, Jakub? This does work well but if there is a better method I would like to explore it.

Comment: @Jakub No argument there, but doing this kind of search is never fast anyway.

Comment: It would depend on the type of search the user is making, STARTS WITH 'TERM%' is faster than CONTAINS '%TERM%', etc;  It really depends on his database schema, the content he searches for, you can always optimize, just look at the way some php search engines work (they index the words and most do exact = 'term' searches which refer back to original search term index / reference.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use a fulltext database as solr or sphinx for this kind of behaviour.
If you can't or don't want to install it, you should add % to your code.
$result = mysql_query( "SELECT id FROM users WHERE " . $key . " LIKE " . "\"%{$str}%\"" ) or die(mysql_error());

Answer (score 1):

you should try

```
$result = mysql_query( "SELECT id FROM users WHERE " . $key . " LIKE " . "%" . $str . "%" ) or die(mysql_error());
```